# PulpSolverError Pulp: Error while executing

Tags: python, pandas, linear-programming, pulp, glpk

I am trying to solve a Linear programming problem by using the PuLP library. After defining the problem correctly, when I run the solver (CBC) I get a very strange error.

> PulpSolverError: Pulp: Error while executing c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pulp\apis..\solverdir\cbc\win\64\cbc.exe

I do not what is the issue, and I think I have hit the wall as I have tried several ways without any success. I also used the following link but it did not help me so I thought to pose it a question: -
[puLP solver error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406858/pulp-solver-error)

The problem defined by me is as follows: -

```
prob = LpProblem('Diet_Problem', LpMinimize)

#Using only the first 17 rows in the data set

df = pd.read_excel('diet.xls',nrows=17)

food = list(df.Foods)

#Create a dictionary of calories for all items of food
calories = dict(zip(food,df['Calories']))
```

Similarly created dictionaries for Carbohydrates, proteins, vitamin_A and other components. Exact similar code was used in each case.

```
# A dictionary called 'food_vars' is created to contain the referenced Variables
food_vars = LpVariable.dicts("Food",food,lowBound=0,cat='Continuous')

#Defined the objective function in the problem
prob += lpSum([costs[i]*food_vars[i] for i in food])

#Defined the constraints and added to the problem
prob += lpSum([food_vars[x]*calories[x] for x in food]) >= 800, "CaloriesMinimum"
prob += lpSum([food_vars[x]*calories[x] for x in food]) <= 1300, "CaloriesMaximum"
```

After defining all this, when I run the solver I get following error: -

```
prob.solve()
```

[image]

A snapshot of the data set is here follows: -

[image]

**Please let me know the solution for this. I have tried all my ways. Thanks in advance**

Comment: something is screwy with your installation of CBC.  CBC is included in the `pulp` install.  Why don't you try to re-install pulp, log out, log back in and try again.

Comment: What do you mean by logging out?
I got the uninstall part

"pip uninstall pulp" 
Is this the code right?

Comment: I mean literally log out or restart your computer.  :)  Anytime you install something that might affect the environment variables (like the solver) sometimes a reset is needed to register the changed env. variables.

Comment: you seam to be using jupyter notebooks, did you take a look at this? https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/guides/how_to_debug.html#jupyter-notebooks-anaconda-conda-issues

Comment: see [a blending problem](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/CaseStudies/a_blending_problem.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. First uninstall pulp and install it again using pip, to make sure it is installed correctly

Then, check your dataframes or data used for the model. In my case, the problem was due to some columns with 'None' or empty values. Removing them using dataframe.dropna() fixed it